# Find the column index which has the maximum value for each row

Tags: pandas, argmax

I have below data frame:

```
   Name1 Scr1 Name2 Scr2 Name3 Scr3
   NY    21   CA    45   SF    37
   AZ    31   BK    46   AK    23
```

I am trying to get the maximum value of each row and corresponding name for each row:

```
df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

But how do i get the corresponding name as well?

Expected Output:

```
   Name Hi_Scr
   CA    45
   BK    46
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

- filter columns with `Scr` by [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), convert values to numpy array by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html)
- get indices of max values with `argmax`
- filter columns with `Name` and select by indexing
- get max values of numeric
- create `DataFrame` by constructor

---

```
a = df.filter(like='Scr').values
b = a.argmax(axis=1)
c = df.filter(like='Name').values[np.arange(len(df.index)), b]
d = a.max(axis=1)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':c, 'Hi_Scr':d}, columns=['Name','Hi_Scr'])
print (df)
  Name  Hi_Scr
0   CA      45
1   BK      46
```

Pandas solution is very similar - create MultiIndex in columns by [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), then select by [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) and for looking values use [`lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
a = df.columns.to_series().str.extract('(\D+)(\d+)', expand=False)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(a.values.tolist())

a = df.xs('Scr', axis=1)
b = a.idxmax(axis=1)
c = df.xs('Name', axis=1).lookup(df.index, b)
d = a.max(axis=1)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':c, 'Hi_Scr':d}, columns=['Name','Hi_Scr'])
print (df)
  Name  Hi_Scr
0   CA      45
1   BK      46
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)


def jez2(df):
    a = df.columns.to_series().str.extract('(\D+)(\d+)', expand=False)
    df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(a.values.tolist())

    a = df.xs('Scr', axis=1)
    b = a.idxmax(axis=1)
    c = df.xs('Name', axis=1).lookup(df.index, b)
    d = a.max(axis=1)

    return pd.DataFrame({'Name':c, 'Hi_Scr':d}, columns=['Name','Hi_Scr'])


def jez1(df):
    a = df.filter(like='Scr').values
    b = a.argmax(axis=1)
    c = df.filter(like='Name').values[np.arange(len(df.index)), b]
    d = a.max(axis=1)

    return  pd.DataFrame({'Name':c, 'Hi_Scr':d}, columns=['Name','Hi_Scr'])

def dark(df):
    df['id'] = df.index
    ndf = pd.wide_to_long(df, ["Name", "Scr"], i="id", j="number").reset_index(0).set_index('Name')
    return ndf.groupby('id')['Scr'].agg(['max','idxmax']).rename(columns= {'max':'Hi_Scr','idxmax':'Name'})
```

---

```
import time

t0 = time.time()
print (jez1(df).head())
t1 = time.time() - t0
print (t1)
print (dark(df).head())
t2 = time.time() - t1
print (t2)
print (jez2(df).head())
t3 = time.time() - t2
print (t3)

  Name  Hi_Scr
0   CA      45
1   BK      46
2   CA      45
3   BK      46
4   CA      45
#jez1 solution
0.015599966049194336
    Hi_Scr Name
id             
0       45   CA
1       46   BK
2       45   CA
3       46   BK
4       45   CA
#dark solution
1515070100.961423
  Name  Hi_Scr
0   CA      45
1   BK      46
2   CA      45
3   BK      46
4   CA      45
#jez2 solution
0.04679989814758301
```

Comment: What do you think of my solution?

Comment: Yeap, I'm practising `wide_to_long`. Cant beat numpy solution ofcourse

Answer (score 7):

I would do it with `pd.wide_to_long` like this :

```
df['id'] = df.index
ndf = pd.wide_to_long(df, ["Name", "Scr"], i="id", j="number").reset_index(0).set_index('Name')

#       id  Scr
# Name         
# NY     0   21
# AZ     1   31
# CA     0   45
# BK     1   46
# SF     0   37
# AK     1   23

# Thank you @jezrael for the improvement
ndf.groupby('id')['Scr'].agg(['max','idxmax']).rename(columns= {'max':'Hi_Scr','idxmax':'Name'})

   Name  Hi Scr
id             
0    CA      45
1    BK      46
```

Comment: Hmm, idea `ndf.groupby('id')['Scr'].agg(['max','idxmax'])` ?

Comment: This used to be mine favorite function :-)

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
df1=df.select_dtypes(include=[object])
df2=df.select_dtypes(exclude=[object])
pd.DataFrame({'Name':df1.values[np.where(df2.eq(df2.max(1),0))],'Scr':df2.max(1)})

Out[342]: 
  Name  Scr
0   CA   45
1   BK   46
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is wrong, because is possible in each row different max. So try change `23` to `230`.

Comment: include and exclude haha nice touch.