# How to find rows with greatest column value, for each index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a dataset from the Federal Elections Commission on US House of Representative campaign spending in the 2018 Midterms. Because it contains all candidates (including those who lost primaries) and I am only interested in general election Democratic candidates, I'm trying to reduce the dataset to nominated Democrats. I've assumed that these will be the Democrats with the highest spending in each district.

The starting dataset is here: https://www.fec.gov/data/candidates/house/?election_year=2018&election_full=True&party=DEM&is_active_candidate=true

I have created a new column, `state_dist`, which is a combination of `state` and `district` with the latter turned to int, then str. This was then sorted by state and district to the following:

[image]

I also have a stacked version, stacking by state and district:

[image]

I have tried borrowing code from [Bharath's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48094572/find-the-column-index-which-has-the-maximum-value-for-each-row). It creates the following:

[image]

The problem is that `max_in_district` appears to return the right values, but I need the candidate name and other variables as well, to attach this to my main project dataframe. I tried adding `name` in `max_in_district_2`, but this doesn't return the result I'm looking for.

To be clear, I want the full row in each `"state_dist"` value which has the highest value in the `"disbursements"` column. How should I get this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Find the `idxmax` and then merge the data back to the original frame:

```
df.set_index('name').groupby(['state_dist'], as_index=False)['disbursements'].idxmax()\
.merge(df, right_on=['name', 'state_dist'], 
       left_on=['disbursements', 'state_dist'])
```

Comment: That solved it. This was a huge help, so thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```py
df.loc[
    df.groupby("state_dist", as_index=False)["disbursements"].idxmax()[
        "disbursements"
    ]
].to_csv("out.csv")
```

This creates `out.csv`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, looks like this works too. Much appreciated!